# sorting strings on java

Tags: java, sorting

I have to ask the user for his/her name in the format first name/second name/ last name/ second last name, and sort it by last name/second name/ first name/ second name. With my code i can access and sort first name second name and second last name, but i can't find the way to access to the first last name. How can i get to that string and show it on the system.out.println?

```
public static void getNameInOfficialFormat(String name) {
    int index = name.indexOf(" ");
    int secondIndex = name.lastIndexOf(" ");
    String secondLastName = "";
    String secondName = "";

    for (int i = index+1; i < name.length(); i++) {
        if (name.charAt(i)==' ') {
            break;
        }else{
            secondName= secondName.concat(""+name.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    for (int i = secondIndex+1; i < name.length(); i++) {
        if (name.charAt(i)==' ') {
            break;
        }else{
            secondLastName= secondLastName.concat(""+name.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    String nameOfUser="";
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
        if (name.charAt(i)==' ') {
            break;
        }else{
            nameOfUser= nameOfUser.concat(""+name.charAt(i));
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Sorted name: " + "\n" +secondLastName + " " + nameOfUser + " " +  secondName);
}
```

Comment: I would start by fixing up your formatting to make it more readable. You on need  a fraction of the lines, and building a a String with a StringBuilder is cleaner.

Comment: Could you please clarify the program's intended input by the user? Is the user entering their first name, second name, and last name independently and in order?

Comment: The user is entering their first name, second name, last name and second last name. That's the order that they program have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user calls the method using a string like John William Doe Jones
then you can use the split method like this:

```
String[] names = name.split(" ");
```

Knowing that he will pass them in order then you will have an array that will contain each name in order and then you can sort it however you like.
You can print it like this:

```
System.out.println("Sorted Name:\n" + names[3] + " " + names[0] + " " + names[1] + " " + names[2]);
```

This will print Jones John Doe William. I am not sure how you want the output but basically names[0] is John (First Name), names[1] is William (Second Name), names[2] is Doe (Last Name) and names[3] is Jones (Second Last Name).

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)